# Mysql Join 2 table and select maximum and minimum value between date range

Tags: mysql, join

i have 2 table, orders and rates. i want to join this two tables and select maximum and minimum value between opentime and closetime

## Table 1 : orders

```
id  type    pair    lot     opentime        openprice   closeprice  closetime 

1   buy     eurusd  0.01    2016-05-02 02:04:07     1.15112     1.14778     2016-05-02 03:05:00

2   sell    gbpusd  0.01    2016-05-02 02:24:17     1.45221     1.44989     2016-05-02 03:05:00
```

## Table 2 : rates

```
id  pair    time            price

10  eurusd  2016-05-02 03:00:00     1.14522

9   gbpusd  2016-05-02 03:00:00     1.44726

8   eurusd  2016-05-02 02:30:00     1.15258

7   gbpusd  2016-05-02 02:30:00     1.45311

6   eurusd  2016-05-02 02:00:00     1.15051

5   gbpusd  2016-05-02 02:00:00     1.45173

4   eurusd  2016-05-01 01:30:00     1.14258

3   gbpusd  2016-05-02 01:30:00     1.44326

2   eurusd  2016-05-02 01:00:00     1.15751

1   gbpusd  2016-05-02 01:00:00     1.45911
```

## expected results

```
id type pair    lot     opentime     openprice closeprice closetime       high    timehigh      low     timelow

1  buy  eurusd  0.01 2016-05-02 02:04:07 1.15112   1.14778    2016-05-02 03:05:00 1.15258 2016-05-02 02:30:00   1.14522 2016-05-02 03:00:00

2  sell gbpusd  0.01 2016-05-02 02:24:17 1.45221   1.44989    2016-05-02 03:05:00 1.45311 2016-05-02 02:30:00   1.44726 2016-05-02 03:00:00
```

i try this query but get empty result

```
SELECT id,type,pair,lot,opentime,openprice,closeprice,closetime,high,timehigh,low,timelow FROM (SELECT id,type,pair,lot,opentime,openprice,closeprice,closetime FROM `order` ORDER BY closetime DESC) table1 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(price) as high,time as timehigh,pair as pairhigh FROM `rates` GROUP BY pair) table2 ON table1.pair=table2.pairhigh 
JOIN (SELECT MIN(price) as low,time as timelow,pair as pairlow FROM `rates` GROUP BY pair) table3 ON table1.pair=table3.pairlow 
WHERE table2.timehigh between table1.opentime and table1.closetime AND table3.timelow between table1.opentime and table1.closetime
```

try query without where clause get result not empty but not expected

```
SELECT id,type,pair,lot,opentime,openprice,closeprice,closetime,high,timehigh,low,timelow FROM (SELECT id,type,pair,lot,opentime,openprice,closeprice,closetime FROM `order` ORDER BY closetime DESC) table1 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(price) as high,time as timehigh,pair as pairhigh FROM `rates` GROUP BY pair) table2 ON table1.pair=table2.pairhigh 
JOIN (SELECT MIN(price) as low,time as timelow,pair as pairlow FROM `rates` GROUP BY pair) table3 ON table1.pair=table3.pairlow
```

## Result

```
id type pair    lot     opentime     openprice closeprice closetime       high    timehigh      low     timelow

1  buy  eurusd  0.01 2016-05-02 02:14:07 1.15112   1.14778    2016-05-02 03:05:00 1.15751 2016-05-02 02:00:00   1.14258 2016-05-02 02:00:00

2  sell gbpusd  0.01 2016-05-02 03:24:17 1.45221   1.44989    2016-05-02 03:05:00 1.45911 2016-05-02 02:00:00   1.44326 2016-05-02 02:00:00
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Is there an sqlfiddle?

Comment: no sqlfiddle @strawberry

Comment: Oh How unfortunate

Comment: why unfortunate @strawberry

Comment: This would have been easier if you'd provided some create/insert statements so people didn't have to type it all out manually to debug

Answer (score 3):

I believe this now matches your requirements?

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
JOIN (SELECT price as maxPrice, pair, tr_time as maxTime FROM Rates
    JOIN (SELECT Rates.pair, MAX(Rates.price) AS price
        FROM Rates, Orders 
        WHERE (Rates.tr_time between Orders.opentime and Orders.closetime) 
        GROUP BY Rates.pair) 
    as MaxPrices USING (price, pair)) maxRates USING (pair)
JOIN (SELECT price AS minPrice, pair, tr_time as minTime FROM Rates
        JOIN (SELECT Rates.pair, MIN(Rates.price) AS price
            FROM Rates, Orders 
            WHERE (Rates.tr_time between Orders.opentime and Orders.closetime) 
            GROUP BY Rates.pair) 
    as minPrices USING (price, pair)) minRates USING (pair);
```

Your code structure is too poor for me to really work out what is going on, but essentially it seems that you were unaware that aggregate operators such as `MAX()` return only a single value.

You've also been unclear on what you wanted the minimum/maximum price of (I've assumed its per `pair`)

Have a run of the code and see if it returns right? If not tell me where it doesn't match and I can start patching it!

**EDIT** 
New results:

[image]

Comment: I believe I have corrected. I'm also convinced theres an error in your expected results - for GBP->USD, 1.44726 @ 0300 is not the lowest in between opening hours , 1.45311 @0230 is lower?

Comment: @Strawberry I've edited again. Change now selects lowest, then joins that to get the correct (determinate) time, then joins that to the overhead table showing start/closure times

Comment: Agreed - because price is non-key. But if you cross-joined and then used a where statement to insist upon equality in both the price & pair fields that would work...

Comment: See update to the code (I know the aggregate statement is now returning two, but the second field is the group-by attribute...)

Comment: thank you @davidhood, your query working as expected. i make little change because GROUP BY Rates.pair not working for same pair, all orders with same pair only display 1 result. also your query is very slow.. taking 25 minutes for 152 row orders and 12k row rates. do you have suggestions how to make your query run faster?

Comment: From my knowledge of DBMS, this can be sped up my replacing the interior cross-products with joins. I've updated my answer to reflect this...although I dont know how much this will help (or not)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it outputs as your expected result, may work for you;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d27a1/9)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
    (`id` int, `type` varchar(4), `pair` varchar(6), `lot` float, `opentime` datetime, `openprice` float, `closeprice` float, `closetime` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO orders
    (`id`, `type`, `pair`, `lot`, `opentime`, `openprice`, `closeprice`, `closetime`)
VALUES
    (1, 'buy', 'eurusd', 0.01, '2016-05-02 02:04:07', 1.15112, 1.14778, '2016-05-02 03:05:00'),
    (2, 'sell', 'gbpusd', 0.01, '2016-05-02 02:24:17', 1.45221, 1.44989, '2016-05-02 03:05:00')
;


CREATE TABLE rates
    (`id` int, `pair` varchar(6), `time` datetime, `price` float)
;

INSERT INTO rates
    (`id`, `pair`, `time`, `price`)
VALUES
    (10, 'eurusd', '2016-05-02 03:00:00', 1.14522),
    (9, 'gbpusd', '2016-05-02 03:00:00', 1.44726),
    (8, 'eurusd', '2016-05-02 02:30:00', 1.15258),
    (7, 'gbpusd', '2016-05-02 02:30:00', 1.45311),
    (6, 'eurusd', '2016-05-02 02:00:00', 1.15051),
    (5, 'gbpusd', '2016-05-02 02:00:00', 1.45173),
    (4, 'eurusd', '2016-05-01 01:30:00', 1.14258),
    (3, 'gbpusd', '2016-05-02 01:30:00', 1.44326),
    (2, 'eurusd', '2016-05-02 01:00:00', 1.15751),
    (1, 'gbpusd', '2016-05-02 01:00:00', 1.45911)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
orders.*, mx.high, R1.time AS timehigh, mn.low, R2.time AS timelow
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT orders.pair, rates.time, max(rates.price) AS high
    FROM orders
    JOIN rates ON orders.pair = rates.pair AND rates.time <= orders.closetime AND rates.time >= orders.opentime
    group by orders.pair
) mx ON mx.pair = orders.pair
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT orders.pair, min(rates.price) AS low, rates.time
    FROM orders
    JOIN rates ON orders.pair = rates.pair AND rates.time <= orders.closetime AND rates.time >= orders.opentime
    GROUP BY orders.pair
) mn ON mn.pair = orders.pair
LEFT JOIN rates R1 ON mx.pair = R1.pair and R1.price = mx.high
LEFT JOIN rates R2 ON mn.pair = R2.pair and R2.price = mn.low
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d27a1/9/0)**:

```
| id | type |   pair |  lot |              opentime | openprice | closeprice |             closetime |    high |                  time |     low |                  time |
|----|------|--------|------|-----------------------|-----------|------------|-----------------------|---------|-----------------------|---------|-----------------------|
|  1 |  buy | eurusd | 0.01 | May, 02 2016 02:04:07 |   1.15112 |    1.14778 | May, 02 2016 03:05:00 | 1.15258 | May, 02 2016 02:30:00 | 1.14522 | May, 02 2016 03:00:00 |
|  2 | sell | gbpusd | 0.01 | May, 02 2016 02:24:17 |   1.45221 |    1.44989 | May, 02 2016 03:05:00 | 1.45311 | May, 02 2016 02:30:00 | 1.44726 | May, 02 2016 03:00:00 |
```

Comment: Wasn't the low at 1:30 ? This isn't going to work. Non-grouped columns in an aggregate result are indeterminate. The downvote is harsh considering the effort, but this solution is wrong.

Comment: As description of question, `rates.time` is between `orders.opentime` and `orders.closetime`, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, perhaps it is. Nevertheless, this STILL produces an indeterminate result.

Comment: @Strawberry If you're sure about my wrong, you can just point it out in my sql, and give us a right answer, why downvote? Even you are at high reputation or you are an expert in MySQL, you just can not deny it and not give us a correct answer. It's not a proper manner in SO. And thanks for your downvote...

Comment: @Strawberry Could you give us a correct answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I think davidhood2's nailed it, but just in case...

```
SELECT a.* 
     , b.price high
     , b.time timehigh
     , c.price low
     , c.time timelow
  FROM orders a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.pair
            , x.price 
            , x.time
         FROM rates x 
         JOIN  
            ( SELECT r.pair
                   , MAX(r.price) price 
                FROM rates r 
                JOIN orders o 
                  ON o.pair = r.pair 
                 AND r.time BETWEEN o.opentime AND o.closetime 
               GROUP 
                  BY pair
            ) y 
           ON y.pair = x.pair 
          AND y.price = x.price
     ) b
    ON b.pair = a.pair
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.pair
            , x.price 
            , x.time
         FROM rates x 
         JOIN  
            ( SELECT r.pair
                   , MIN(r.price) price 
                FROM rates r 
                JOIN orders o 
                  ON o.pair = r.pair 
                 AND r.time BETWEEN o.opentime AND o.closetime 
               GROUP 
                  BY pair
            ) y 
           ON y.pair = x.pair 
          AND y.price = x.price
     ) c
    ON c.pair = a.pair;

+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id   | type | pair   | lot  | opentime            | openprice | closeprice | closetime           | high    | timehigh            | low     | timelow             |
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
|    1 | buy  | eurusd | 0.01 | 2016-05-02 02:04:07 |   1.15112 |    1.14778 | 2016-05-02 03:05:00 | 1.15258 | 2016-05-02 02:30:00 | 1.14522 | 2016-05-02 03:00:00 |
|    2 | sell | gbpusd | 0.01 | 2016-05-02 02:24:17 |   1.45221 |    1.44989 | 2016-05-02 03:05:00 | 1.45311 | 2016-05-02 02:30:00 | 1.44726 | 2016-05-02 03:00:00 |
+------+------+--------+------+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Wow, I have no idea what is the essential difference between your answer and mine...I just put the `left join rates` out of subquery, what a thankful downvote!!!

Comment: @Reno - I did already explain the essential difference. It's not the left join. It's the indeterminacy of your result.